# Keras LSTM using batch outputs incorrect shape

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm currently trying to implement a LSTM network.
The network itself looks as follows

```
self.time_steps = 1
self.num_actions = 6
self.lstm_units = 64
input = Input(shape=(self.time_steps, self.num_actions))
h = Input(shape=(1, 64))
c = Input(shape=(1, 64))
LSTM_layer = LSTM(self.lstm_units, return_sequences=False, return_state=True)
lstm_output, out_h, out_c = LSTM_layer(input, initial_state=[h, c])
logit = Dense(self.num_actions, name="logit")(lstm_output)
output = Activation('softmax')(logit)

self.model = Model(inputs=[input, h, c], outputs=[output, out_h, out_c])
```

When I try to predict the outcome of the network by using

```
input = np.zeros((16, self.time_steps, self.num_actions))
h = np.zeros((16, 1, self.lstm_units))
c = np.zeros((16, 1, self.lstm_units))
policy, h, c = self.model.predict([input, h, c])
```

An error appears

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (256,6) into shape (16,6)
```

However, if I change the batch size to 1 (so all the appearances of 16 is replaced with 1), the network can give a correct output.  Does anyone know what the issue is?
It seems that the incorrect shape is always batch^2, so if I set it as 12 instead of 16, it complains about (144, 6) instead (which is why 1 works I guess, because 1^2=1...)

EDIT: Added more info on error

```
 File "D:\Projects\file\file.py", line 123, in generate_network
    policy, h, c = self.model.predict([input, h, c])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1167, in predict
    steps=steps)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 302, in predict_loop
    outs[i][batch_start:batch_end] = batch_out
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (256,6) into shape (16,6)
```

Comment: Can you post stack trace as well to see where exactly code is facing error?

Comment: @UpasanaMittal I've now added where it's giving out the error

Answer (score 0):

Okay, So I tried your code and same error reproduced when I used the code given here that means, you are trying to predict directly without training the model. Correct me if I am wrong!
At first, You need to compile the model and fit to the data to train it. Only after that you will be able to predict on some data. Something like this:

```
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.summary()
    model.fit(features, np.array(label), validation_split = 0.5, epochs=20, batch_size=64, class_weight=class_weights_dict)
```

Comment: Sorry for the ultra late reply.
I tried to compile it first, but the result is still the same, so I don't think that's where the issue is (like I said, batch of 1 works).  I need to predict first before I can train the model, since the labels are from the model output.